# 6 Piece Wooden Puzzle

Tags: puzzle-identification

I have been attempting to solve this puzzle that didn’t come with directions. [image: pieces]

Comment: You could find online some hints. It seems that this one is similar (if not identical) to your puzzle: https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~storer/JimPuzzles/BURR/SetSimple6/SetSimple6.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I think the puzzle is a *variation* of Jürg von Känel's *Coated Burr Puzzle*.
In your case there are twelve solutions. Find your pieces and assemble them as shown in the picture (for one of them).
[image]

[image]